# mutate () with case_when() creates a weird column name why?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

```
Data   <- Data %>%
      mutate((dara = case_when(HIV_result == 1  &  vSupressed == 1 ~ 0,
HIV_result == 1 & vSupressed == 0 & Condomlessex == "Yes"  ~ 1,
HIV_result == 1 & vSupressed == 0 & Condomlessex == "No" & (Y_chromosome == 1|STI == 1)  ~ 1,
HIV_result == 1  &  vSupressed == 0  &  Condomlessex == "No"  &  (Y_chromosome == 0 & STI == 0)  ~ 0,
TRUE ~ 0))  )
```

I find a weird column name (...) instead of dara
what am I doing wrong?

here is the data

```r
    HIV_result    <- c(rep(1,6), rep(0,12), rep(1,2))  # 1 = "Positive" and 0 =  "Negative"
    vSupressed    <- c(rep(1,1), rep(0,5),  rep(0,13), rep(1,1))  # 1 = "Suppressed" and 0 =  "Unsuppressed" defined by viral load threshold

    currentPREP   <- c(rep("No",8), rep("Yes",4), rep("No",8))   #  "Yes" and  "No"
    PrEPtest      <- c(rep(0,8), rep(0,5),rep(1,7))              #  1 = "Positive" and 0 =  "Negative"

    Condomlessex  <- c(rep("Yes",2), rep("No",4), rep("Yes",7), rep("No",6), rep("Yes",1))                #  "Yes" and  "No"
    Y_chromosome  <- c(rep(1,4), rep(0,4), rep(1,2), rep(0,6), rep(1,4))    # 1 = "Positive" and 0 =  "Negative"
    STI           <- c(rep(1,3), rep(0,1), rep(1,1), rep(0,2), rep(1,7), rep(0,6))    # 1 = "Positive" and 0 =  "Negative       # PrepLevel applies only for currentPrEP and PrEPtest
    dAMETHIST   <- data.frame(cbind(HIV_result, vSupressed, Condomlessex, Y_chromosome, STI, currentPREP, PrEPtest))
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the outer bracket around the `dara`.  When, we are blocking the code and there is no column name before it, it just adds that

```
Data %>%
      mutate(dara = case_when(HIV_result == 1  &  vSupressed == 1 ~ 0,
HIV_result == 1 & vSupressed == 0 & Condomlessex == "Yes"  ~ 1,
HIV_result == 1 & vSupressed == 0 & Condomlessex == "No" & (Y_chromosome == 1|STI == 1)  ~ 1,
HIV_result == 1  &  vSupressed == 0  &  Condomlessex == "No"  &  (Y_chromosome == 0 & STI == 0)  ~ 0,
TRUE ~ 0)  )
```

-output

```
   HIV_result vSupressed Condomlessex Y_chromosome STI currentPREP PrEPtest dara
1           1          1          Yes            1   1          No        0    0
2           1          0          Yes            1   1          No        0    1
3           1          0           No            1   1          No        0    1
4           1          0           No            1   0          No        0    1
5           1          0           No            0   1          No        0    1
6           1          0           No            0   0          No        0    0
7           0          0          Yes            0   0          No        0    0
8           0          0          Yes            0   1          No        0    0
9           0          0          Yes            1   1         Yes        0    0
10          0          0          Yes            1   1         Yes        0    0
11          0          0          Yes            0   1         Yes        0    0
12          0          0          Yes            0   1         Yes        0    0
13          0          0          Yes            0   1          No        0    0
14          0          0           No            0   1          No        1    0
15          0          0           No            0   0          No        1    0
16          0          0           No            0   0          No        1    0
17          0          0           No            1   0          No        1    0
18          0          0           No            1   0          No        1    0
19          1          0           No            1   0          No        1    1
20          1          1          Yes            1   0          No        1    0
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocking.  And in which scenario this could be relevant? Thanks!

Comment: @TarJae OP put a `(dara = ...)` which is unnecessary

Comment: @TarJae Blocking with `{}` or `()` are when there are multiple expressions.  Here it is not the case i.e. all the expressions are joined with logical operators in `case_when`.  Also, those blocking should be outside the column name